# Last element of ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-select2

Given the following piece of code:

```
<select label="someSelect" 
        ng-model="someModel" 
        ng-options="p as p.bar group by p.foo for p in ps">
</select>
```

Is there out a way to know when the select has been populated with the corresponding option values?

I know this can be achieved within `ng-repeat` directive creating a custom directive and checking `scope.$last` property but this doesn't seem to work in this case.

The idea behind this is that I want to be able to use Select2 plugin (http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/). Since `someModel` doesn't match any value of the provided options, `ng-options` adds by default an extra `<option value="?"></option>` (as Josep already pointed out). A possible solution might be initializing this scope property (`someModel`) in the controller with a valid value, but the data provided (`ps` in this case) might be empty, so no initialization value is possible.

My first approach is to know when the select rendering has finished, so that I can remove the extra option value and initialize properly the selext box again and again as the model changes.

Is it actually possible? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: so, you want to know when the ng-options directive has finished rendering the items? I assume that you want to know when it has finished rendering in order to recalculate the positions or something like that, correct?

Comment: @Josep that's it. I need to know it so that I can modify the DOM accordingly to make some plugin work (http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/), since ng-options adds by default an empty option value every time the model changes.

Comment: well then, I'm sorry but I'm afraid that this is an x/y question. You would be better off explaining what your real issue is. Also, it's not true that "ng-options adds by default an empty option value every time the model changes", ngOptions will add a default empty option when the value of your model doesn't match any of the possible values of your options.

Comment: @Josep indeed, I wanted to simplify my question. I will update it properly, thanks.

Comment: I just posted an answer, please let me know if that what you were looking for ;). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I think that what you want is something like this:

A directive in order to use select2 (rule of thumb: always use directives when you want to integrate an external plugin):

```
.directive('select2', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link : function (scope, element, attrs ) {
      $timeout(function(){element.select2();});
    } 
  };
});
```

Your HTML:

```
<select 
ng-init="studentSelected=students[0]" 
ng-model="studentSelected" 
ng-options="student.name group by student.class for student in students" 
select2>
</select>
```

### [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/TvaPXiEdrHbq2IbIJZfH)

Also, it's worth to mention that since you are using `select2` which requires `jQuery`, the `element` that you receive in your directive is not a `jqLite` object, but a `jQuery` object, that's why you can just do `element.select2()` inside the directive.

Comment: This worked like a charm, thanks Josep :) As a comment, `ng-init` doesn't seem to be required. Thanks for the explanation as well!